# readImageBlob function from Imagick is throwing an error like 'No Decode Delegate For This Image Format'

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, imagick

I'm working on a PHP project, using PHP Version 5.4.7, which can customize an image online and display the customization for site admin. Image format is png. Imagick, the php native function is used to read and save the image as a pdf.

Below shown is the code snippet which I used.

```
$datadec = base64_decode($data);        
        $dpi = 300;
        $printable_width = ($dims['printable_width'] * $dpi)/25.4;
        $printable_height = ($dims['printable_height'] * $dpi)/25.4;

        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->setResolution(300, 300);
        $im->readImageBlob($datadec);
        $im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);      
        $settings = include '../data/settings.php';
        $format = $settings['print_format'];
```

But it is throwing an error like

> Type: ImagickException  Code: 420  Message:
>   NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/358

And the Slim error trace is like

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\XXXX\admin\controllers\OrdersController.php(151): Imagick->readimageblob('?PNG????????IHD...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\XXXX\admin\controllers\OrdersController.php(305): OrdersController->convertHiRes('data:image/png;...', Array, '../storage/orde...')
#2 [internal function]: OrdersController->postPrint()
```

I've a doubt about the Imagick installation also. But most of the forums are answering based on Linux environment. I'm a beginner and don't really know about those commands.

### Update

Actually I got the image from a canvas element using JavaScript:

```
var file = canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier('png', multiplier, 1);
```

and this is posted to the php file, which I mentioned before... There I done this to set the $data...,

```
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $image);
list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
```

I'm using XAMPP in a Windows environment.

Comment: where have you encode `$data` ? have tried without `base64_decode` use $data direct. `$im->readImageBlob($data);`

Comment: yeah, I've tried that also. But didn't worked as well. Got the same error.

Comment: so please show where you set `$data` !

Comment: Actually I got the image from a canvas element using javascript,  var file = canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier('png', multiplier, 1); and this is posted to the php file, which I mentioned before... There I done this to set the $data..., list($type, $data) = explode(';', $image);
  list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

Comment: and where is your `base64_encode($data);` before `post` ?

Comment: I didn't encoded separately. I got the image code using the method toDataURLWithMultiplier from fabric.js. The result itself is in an encoded form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

important is that the modules match. You have php 5.4.7

These two are tested by me and fit.

- look for `5.4 Thread Safe (TS) x86` download here

https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows

you only need `php_imagick.dll`
Find and Place the `php_imagick.dll` in your extension folder
It is usually `php/ext/`.

open the `C:\Windows\php.ini`

Uncomment if it exists or add if it doesnt exist this line

`extension=php_imagick.dll`

- Download [ImageMagick-6.6.5-10-Q8-windows-dll.exe](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.6.5-10-Q8-windows-dll.exe) .

That's the only place where I've found an old 6.6.5

- Install the exe file and **do the test is proposed** at the end of the installation. Copy and paste the commands in a cmd window.
- Test for `ImageMagick-6.6.5-Q8` in the path.

[image]

- Important files comes with the installation

[image]

---

- Test `php_imagick.dll` with `Dependency Walker` that all `dll`s are inplace.
  all found , nothing red !

[image]

[image]

---

- Test with Php_info

[image]

- Now it's a good time to **Restart** the computer.

### Test in Netbeans

Open netbeans and create a new `Project`

[image]

you can also run index.php with cmd

> "G:\php\php.exe" "U:\Programme\NetBeans80\dtx\PngHeader\index.php"

index.php

```
<?php
$filename = "canvas.png";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r+");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

$im = new Imagick();
$im->queryFormats();
$im->readImageBlob($contents);
/* Thumbnail the image */
$im->thumbnailImage(200, null);
/* Create a border for the image */
$im->borderImage(new ImagickPixel("white"), 5, 5);
/* Clone the image and flip it */
$reflection = $im->clone();
$reflection->flipImage();
/* Create gradient. It will be overlayed on the reflection */
$gradient = new Imagick();
/* Gradient needs to be large enough for the image and the borders */
$gradient->newPseudoImage($reflection->getImageWidth() + 10, $reflection->getImageHeight() + 10, "gradient:transparent-black");
/* Composite the gradient on the reflection */
$reflection->compositeImage($gradient, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

/* Add some opacity. Requires ImageMagick 6.2.9 or later */
$reflection->setImageOpacity( 0.3 );

/* Create an empty canvas */
$canvas = new Imagick();

/* Canvas needs to be large enough to hold the both images */
$width = $im->getImageWidth() + 40;
$height = ($im->getImageHeight() * 2) + 30;
$canvas->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel("black"));
$canvas->setImageFormat("png");

/* Composite the original image and the reflection on the canvas */
$canvas->compositeImage($im, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 20, 10);
$canvas->compositeImage($reflection, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 20, $im->getImageHeight() + 10);

$filename = "canvasNew.png";
$handle = fopen($filename, "wb");
if ($handle){
  fwrite( $handle, $canvas);
  fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

canvas.png

[image]

result canvasNew.png

[image]

Example are also [here](http://php.net/manual/de/imagick.examples-1.php)

Comment: imagemagick is installed. And also there is a condition to check whether it is installed or not. But I have doubt in decode delegate. So I raised another question also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32442085/5226917

Comment: @JTheDev : you must exactly install the ImageMagick version that fits your 5.4.7 PHP !!!! What's your ImageMagick version ?

Comment: @JTheDev No, I mean `ImageMagick` library Version. But for the wrapper `php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6` it's wrong you need `php_imagick-3.1.2-5.4` !!!

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, but it didn't worked. I dropped that functionality. Thanks a lot for the help...

Comment: @JTheDev : I've made a `step by step`. Please try it.

Comment: really appreciate your effort, and a great thank you in advance. I'll check it and get back to you... Thanks again