# How to install decode delegate for Imagick in Xampp on Windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp, imagick

I've gone through many post related to the installation of Imagick and the decode delegates. But most of them were only based on a Linux environment. I'm working on Xampp (Xampp 1.8.1 and PHP Version 5.4.7) in a Windows environment. I'm not used to these commands.

How can I install the decode delegates for Imagick. I am also seeking a way to check the status of these components (whether it is installed or not).

Comment: Please edit your previous question instead of asking an almost exact duplicate, and then delete this question.

Comment: I need only a solution. And I'm running here and there to find the exact cause also. Please don't mind my eagerness...